# How to create a view for a single control?

Tags: prism

What is the best way to create a view for a single control that I need to load into a Shell region in a Prism app. I know I can wrap the control in a UserControl, but I suspect there may be a better way.

I am working on a demo app to learn Prism 4. Each module will load a navigation button into an ItemsControl in a region in the Shell. These navigation buttons will function like the Mail, Calendar, and other buttons in Outlook.

I am creating the view in each module that will hold the module's navigation button. The simplest way to create the view seems to be to wrap it in a UserControl. My question is this: Is there a better way to do it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need graphical control, what you are doing is the way to go. If you find yourself making all of the buttons look the same (copy - pasting) you might find that a menu registration service is the way to go.

You'd have a service like IMenuService that you register with your container and modules can come around and register menu items to. You can then create buttons for the module. I've provided a sample for this here:
http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/376992/CAGMenus.zip

Your question, though, seems to be about whether or not you *need* to wrap a control in a UserControl to register them with a region? If that's the question, I believe the answer is *no*, although you might amend your question to tell us what you are running up against that makes you think this.

Comment: Answer accepted, although I do think I need to use the UserControl wrapper, at least with a plain-vanilla Class Library project. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping the control in a UserControl, and it seems to work fine. I am still interested in seeing if there is a better way to load the button, so I will hold this question open for a few days.

**Edit 02/22/2011:** I tried using a control without a UserControl wrapper, and I got the following error:

`Library project file cannot specify ApplicationDefinition element.`

I wrapped the control in a UserControl and the error went away.

Comment: It's still hard to know exactly what your scenario is, but if I had to guess, I'd say this is more a limitation of the type of project you chose, rather than a WPF specific limitation. A User Control library would have less limitations, I think.